# Windows 10 Event Viewer: Asks for disk check on non-existing volume

Tags: windows-10, ntfs, chkdsk, event-viewer

When checking the event viewer, Windows will log the following error:

> Volume \?\Volume{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx} {\Device\0000003f} needs to be taken offline for a short period to perform a Spot Fix. Please run "CHKDSK /SPOTFIX" locally via the command line, or run "REPAIR-VOLUME " locally or remotely via PowerShell

This error shows up for several different GUIDs.

Using *mountvol* to check all the volumes on my PC to which Windows has given a GUID gives several results, but the GUID that the event viewer reports doesn't show up. Neither of them show up in that list.
They also don't show up at ***HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices*** in the registry keys.

To what volume might Windows be referring, what are the possible problems this might cause, and how can I suppress this problem (since running diskchecks is impossible on unexisting volumes)?

Comment: If you have a RAID array, sometimes Windows gets confused and tries to access the physical drives directly for some reason. You might need to do some repair-work on the RAID.

Comment: I don't have a RAID array